# FFMPEG Stdout Line

Tags: ffmpeg, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I'm just wondering why Google Colab doesn't show FFMPEG's STDOUT line, showing the frame progress, fps, duration, time elapsed, etc. Jupyter notebooks and jupyter lab shows it, so I'm not sure why colab doens't. Thanks in advance.

When running the ffmpeg command, (!ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4), there is no stdout line in google colab, but if run in jupyter notebooks, the stdout lines show. Just curious why this is.

Comment: ffmpeg logs to stderr, because ffmpeg media can be piped over stdout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Forgive my incorrect statement, but the question still lies, why does ffmpeg in Google Colab not print the "frame= duration= size= " etc line?

Comment: What's your full command?

Comment: !ffmpeg -i "/content/input.mp4" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast -y "/content/ouput.mp4" 

Forgive me, but if I may, the issue doesn't lie with the command, as I've tested it using -loglevel verbose, which still doesn't print the "frame" line, and -loglevel trace prints a new "frame" line every frame which overloads the browser. I simply wonder why Colab doesn't display the stderr line, but Jupyter does. Especially since Colab is based off of Jupyter, it doesn't make sense to me atm.